# Show that function distances are preserved

Tags: analysis, combinatorial-geometry

If for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfies $|x - y| = t$ also satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)|=t$ (for some constant $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$), show that $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y|$ for all values of $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

This seems very much intuitive to me and that $f(x) = x$ or that the range set is a copy of $\mathbb{R}^n$. My initial goal was to show if $r \in l(x,y)$, then $f(r) \in l(f(x),f(y))$ such that $|f(r)-f(z)| = |r - z|$ where $z \in \{x,y\}$. Showing this is enough to solve the problem. The most intuitive idea, however that seems to work is creating equilateral triangles in some way and make it work.

$\color{green}{\text{Edit :}}$ In $\mathbb{R}$, by taking $f$ as the greatest integer function with a period of $t$, we get a clear contradiction to the initial statement. The idea doesn't seem to directly work for higher dimensions, albeit the first answer claims so. Can *this* (or the claim in the original question) be proven for $n > 1$?

Comment: What if $f$ have derivative?

Comment: @zkutch Do you mean solving it by assuming the existence of a derivative?

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is handy to simplify problem, solve it and then look for generalization.

Comment: Well, as is I can't see how this can be true in general. Take $t=0$ then $x=y\implies f(x)=f(y)$ is just a triviality. It won't magically makes $f$ an isometry.

Comment: I should've mentioned $t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Updated!

Comment: $f$ is a function to $\Bbb R^n$, not necessarily continuous, right?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Not necessarily. But it would be interesting to know both sides of the cion (ie, the result when $f$ is continuous and when it is not)

Comment: An answer also depends on the dimension $m$ of the image of $f$, because there are counterexamples provided $m+1$ is not smaller than the [chromatic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) of $\Bbb R^n$. Indeed, given a coloring of $\Bbb R^n$ into $k$ colors such that no monochromatic class contains two points at distance $t$, let $f$ be any map from $\Bbb R^n$ to $\Bbb R^{k-1}$, mapping monochromatic classes to vertices of a regular simplex with edge $t$.

Answer (score 3):

This is true in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge2$ and it is wrong in $\mathbb{R}$.
First not that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ preserves the distance $t$ if and only if $\widetilde{f}(x)\triangleq\frac{1}{t}f(tx)$ preserves the distance $1$. So, we may suppose that $t=1$ without loss of generality.

- If $n=1$ then the function
  $$f(x)=\cases{x+1&if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$,\\
  x&if $x\notin\mathbb{Z}$.}$$
  is a counter-example.
- If $n>1$ then it is [Beckman-Quarles theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beckman%E2%80%93Quarles_theorem) that date back to 1953. The article is freely accessible [here](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1953-0058193-5).

Answer (score -2):

I don't think this is true without further hypothesis (continuity maybe), because we can build counter examples with periodic stuff or similar.

In $\mathbb R$ take $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $t=1$. Then $f(\frac12)-f(\frac 13)=0\neq \frac 12-\frac 13$.

I think we can extend that to higher dimensions without too much issues.

Comment: I get how this could work for $t \neq 1$ when in $\mathbb{R}$. How would you extend this to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: This is not by massive downvotes you will give me incentives to investigate more. And surely not how it will motivate others to try their chance.

Comment: That's how stack works. I see genuine questions being asked and down-voted for no rhyme or reason whatsoever. People defend their fellow SErs by saying "You have been down-voted probably because you had something wrong" which is not what I expect from MSE. I down-voted it since "this answer is not useful" to me. I will take my share of down-vote back once the answer is edited (It is not possible otherwise). Thank you!